# Why does cron on CentOS  complain about carriage returns?

Tags: cron, centos6

I have a CentOS 6 machine I am trying to run some cronjobs on and the jobs are failing complaining about a carriage return (^M) on the end of the line. Example `/var/log/cron` entry:

```
CROND[20344]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/somescript.php >/dev/null 2>&1^M)
CROND[20213]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/somescript.php^M)
```

All this works fine on CentOS 5.x, so looks like it's a CentOS 6 thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe the master control program can help? he was always fond of end-of-lines ?

Answer (score 3):

Use an editor that uses the correct line organisation. A quick fix is

```
export EDITOR=vi
crontab -e
:1,$s/^V^M//g
:wq
```

where `^V^M` is <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

How are you editing the crontab file?  Was it copied using any Windows systems, notepad, etc?

These are not UNIX linebreaks.  The ^M is a hard carriage return (sometimes known as \r when using escape sequences.)  Windows line endings are \r\n (Carriage return, Line Feed) while UNIX line endings are simply \n.

If you used ASCII-mode FTP, or a Windows text editor at any point to get the file contents on the new CentOS system, that's likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install `dos2unix` and convert it to Unix line ending:

```
# dos2unix /var/spool/cron/root
```

Comment: Don't forget cron's law: You shall not edit the cron file by hand. See Iain's answer how to do it the right way.